# Mathf.Clamp is resetting my eulerangle to minValue in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions, euler-angles, clamp

**Mathf.Clamp is resetting my eulerangle to minValue when it reaches the maxValue instead of constraining it at maxValue. I have tried This :**

```
            rotateX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * senseX;
        player.transform.Rotate(player.up, Mathf.Deg2Rad * rotateX, Space.World);

        playerXRotation = player.eulerAngles;

        while (playerXRotation.y > 180f)
            playerXRotation.y -= 360f;

        Debug.Log("Y Rotation: " + playerXRotation.y);
        playerXRotation.y = Mathf.Clamp(playerXRotation.y, lowLimitY, highLimitY);
        player.transform.eulerAngles = playerXRotation;
```

**And This :**

```
         rotate = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * senseX;
         rotation = player.transform.eulerAngles;
         rotation.y += rotate * RateOfRotate;

         while (rotation.y > 180)
         {
             rotation.y -= 360;
         }
         rotation.y = Mathf.Clamp(rotation.y, lowLimitY, highLimitY);
         player.transform.eulerAngles = rotation;
```

**Here my lowLimitY = 0 and highLimitY = 180 in both the cases; I am stuck at this and have no clue how to work around it. Any help will be appreciated.**

Comment: Well, if the value is being clamped to _lowLimitY_, then it means the value to be clamped was less than _lowLimitY_. Looking at your `while` loops there i wouldn't be surprised if `playerXRotation.y` and `playerXRotation.y` actually are negative after the `while` loop has been executed...

Comment: @elgonzo what do you suggest I should do because without that `while` loop the opposite happens, when _lowLimitY_ is reached instead of clamping it to its value at _0_ it resets it to _highLimitY_ value which is _180_.

Comment: I don't really know what you should do (i do not really have Unity3D experience to give meaningful suggestions), but testing whether the y value is larger than 180 and then going to substract twice that amount isn't looking proper...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Because rotations are quaternions

And they get converted to Euler angles with range [0-360), so `while (rotation.y > 180)` will never work.

You need to track the rotation value separately, clamp to desired values, *then* apply it to the object's rotation.

```
rotation = player.transform.eulerAngles;
float rotationY = rotation.y + rotate * RateOfRotate;
rotationY = Mathf.Clamp(rotationY, lowLimitY, highLimitY);
rotation.y = rotationY;
player.transform.eulerAngles = rotation;
```

Answer (score -1):

If your

`lowLimit = 0`, and `highLimit = 180`, and you run:

```
while (rotation.y > 180)
{
  rotation.y -= 360; 
}
```

If in the case your rotation is the maxValue (180), then rotation.y would equal -180 (180 - 360 = -180).

Then your clamp is `Mathf.Clamp(-180, 0, 180) // 0`

If you're trying to keep the y rotation in that range, then removing the while should do the trick. If you're going for a different effect, we will need more information.

Comment: when I remove that while loop the opposite happens, when `lowLimitY` is reached instead of clamping it to its value at `0` it resets it to `highLimitY` value which is `180`.

Comment: @Kaustav Your limits are just wrong in any case. There are 360 degrees in a circle and your clamp is restricting things to 180 degrees. It doesn't matter how you get the value that goes into it (loop or no loop) the limits are wrong.

Comment: @Draco18s I am trying to restrict the movement between 0 to 180 degrees, I don't need a full 360 degree rotation. That's why I am clamping the value of eulerangle.y between 0 and 180 degrees. And I don't get how can the limits be wrong? Can you please explain what you meant.

Comment: @Kaustav If your thing is rotated 179 degrees and your `RateOfRotate` is 5, what do you *want* to happen? Odds are you want the thing to squish up against the 180 degree barrier. But right now you're going "184? that's more than 180!" and subtracting 360, making it -176, then clamping it to 0. Only when you removed the loop and it the rotation bashed up against the 180 degree limit that was also somehow not what you wanted? *If your thing is rotated 179 degrees and your `RateOfRotate` is 5, what do you **want** to happen?*

Comment: @Draco18s I have tried removing the loop, when I remove the loop my gameobject bashes against the 180 degree limit and is properly clamped to the maxvalue, but when it bashes against the minimum value of 0 degree it somehow gets reset back to the maxvalue of 180 degree instead of being clamped back to 0 degree.

Comment: Probably because euler angles aren't the native storage type, but quaternions, and when it gets converted, those values are above 180...not negative.